# how do I prevent get/set function from exposing a local property in Typescript

Tags: typescript

In Javascript I can create a property of object with get/set methods :

```
function Field(arg){
    var value = arg;

    // Create a read only property "name"
    Object.defineProperty(this, "value", {           
        get: function () {
            return value;
        },
        set: function () {
            console.log("cannot set");
        }
    });
}

var obj = new Field(10);    
console.log(obj.value); // 10
obj.value = 20;         // "cannot set"
```

Setting `value` property is disallowed here.

In TypeScript if I want to achieve the same behaviour I would have to do this (as suggested by [get and set in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12827266/2788872)):

```
class Field {
    _value: number;

    constructor(arg) {
        this._value = arg;
    }

    get value() {
        return this._value;
    }

    set value() {
        console.log("cannot set");
    }
}

var obj = new Field(10);

console.log(obj.value); // 10
obj.value = 20;         // "cannot set"
obj._value = 20;        // ABLE TO CHANGE THE VALUE !
console.log(obj.value); // 20
```

But the problem as you see here is that the so-called private property `_value` can be accessed/changed by the user directly without going through get/set methods for `value`. How do I restrict the user from accessing this property (`_value`) directly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Object.defineProperty` in TypeScript as well.

I've modified your Field class like:

```
class Field{
    value: any;
    constructor(arg: any)
    {
        var value = arg;
        Object.defineProperty(this, "value",{           
            get: () => {
                return value;
            },
            set: function () {
                console.log("cannot set");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Note** that you cannot use the value defined on the class itself, otherwise the getter of the field would be recursively called until you'd run into a `Maximum call stack size exceeded`. The `value:any` declaration on the class definition avoids the compiler error:

> the property "value" does not exist on value of type Field

You can then execute this TypeScript code to get the same results as your JavaScript code example:

```
var obj = new Field(10);
console.log(obj.value);
obj.value = 20;
```

Answer (score 1):

Within TypeScript it should be as simple as adding the `private` modifier (in your example, `_value` is public):

```
private _value:number;
```

... the compiler should now prevent you from setting the property from outside the class:

```
var obj = new Field(10);
obj._value = 20; // Error: The property '_value' does not exist on value of type 'Field'.
```

But this doesn't hide `_value` in the same way in the output JS. TypeScript private members are private only within TS. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12713659/typescript-private-members) and the interesting [codeplex discussion](https://typescript.codeplex.com/discussions/397651) it links to.

Comment: In my case, I don't want _value to be accessed in JS as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize it with the [`readonly` modifier.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#readonly)

```js
class Field {
    readonly _value: number;

    constructor(arg) {
        this._value = arg;
    }
}
```

Makes for a much cleaner implementation.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't create a variable, it will not be accessible:

```
class Field{
    get value(){
        return 10;
    }

    set value(){
        console.log("cannot set");
    }
}

var obj = new Field();
console.log(obj.value); // 10
obj.value = 20;  // cannot set
console.log(obj.value); // 10
```

Ofcourse I would recommend removing the set all-together:

```
class Field{
    get value(){
        return 10;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Basarat, appreciate your prompt responses. I think I didn't make my question clear. Edited it just now. Please have a look again.