# How can I make a class private in my method and interface with typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a class in my application

```
class MyClass {
    doTask1 = () => {
        doTask2();
    }
    doTask2 = () => {

    }
}
```

How can I set up an interface file and how do I decorate my methods for this so that doTask1 is public and doTask2 is private?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember - Interfaces can only contain public methods:

```
interface IMyClass {
    doTask1(): void;
}

class MyClass implements IMyClass {
    doTask1 = () => {
        this.doTask2();
    }
    doTask2 = () => {

    }
}


var instance: IMyClass = new MyClass();
instance.doTask1(); // Ok
instance.doTask2(); // Error
```

Runnable Example: http://bit.ly/Uzkv7V

Btw, You should probably structure your class like this:

```
class MyClass implements IMyClass {
    doTask1() {
        this.doTask2();
    }
    private doTask2() {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> How can I set up an interface file

Javascript does not strictly have interfaces, [see this stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3710275/does-javascript-have-the-interface-type-such-as-javas-interface)

> how do I decorate my methods for this so that doTask1 is public and doTask2 is private?

In Javascript, the idea of public and private is sort of not there, although many people follow the convention of appending and underscore to the variable or function name (such as `_foo`) to let others know it was meant to be private. However, you can control access to variables, [here is a good explanation of that](http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html) written by Douglas Crockford.

**EDIT**

For TypeScript specifically, I'd checkout out the [MSDN article on interfaces](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/typescript/archive/2013/01/24/interfaces-walkthrough.aspx), and I think that [this stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16919473/private-functions-in-typescript) is relevant to your question about private functions.

Comment: Sorry I mean I am using Typescript which has interfaces and classes.

Comment: Right, I picked that up based on the title. I've never used Typescript, but I do know that it compiles to plain old JS so I figured that might help