# Angular2: How to make a function not accessible from UI (view)?

Tags: javascript, angular

All the functions that I am making in a component are accessible to the view even the `private` functions.

**HTML**

```
 <p (click)="accessable(name)">{{name}}</p>
 <p (click)="shouldNotBeAccessable(name)">{{name}}</p>
```

**Component**

```
accessable(item): void{
        this.selected = item;
}
private shouldNotBeAccessable(item):void{
        this.selected = item;
}
```

**Problem**

I don't want the `shouldNotBeAccessable` to be accessible from the view.

**Request**

Is it possible to stop the function to stop being used from view? If yes then how?

Comment: Private methods will fail when you build with AoT. Otherwise I don't think there is a way, because privacy won't be enforced at runtime because JavaScript doesn't know about that concept.

Comment: Nothing private in JavaScript. Typescript is superset. You can emulate though. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16919473/private-functions-in-typescript

Comment: I am totally agree... However I am trying to find out that is it possible to reveal only the relevant variables and functions to the UI? and what about `closures`, cannot we achieve the encapsulation using them?