# TypeScript getter setter convention

Tags: angular, typescript

What is the convention (standard) in TypeScript for class attributes?

In the Angular 2 demo (The Heroes Tour from angular.io), all attributes are set to public:

```
export class Hero {
   id: number;
   name: string;
}
```

So they can be instantiated both ways:

```
var hero: Hero = new Hero();
hero.id = 0;
hero.name = "hero";
```

or

```
var hero2: Hero = {id : 0, name: "hero"};
```

Is there a Java style convention (like this):

```
export class Hero {
   private id: number;
   private name: string;

   setId(id: number): Hero {
      this.id = id;
      return this;
   }

   setName(name: string): Hero {
      this.name = name;
      return this;
   }

   getId(): number {
      return this.id;
   }

   getName(): string {
      return this.name;
   }
}
```

Declaration (example):

```
var hero: Hero = new Hero();
hero.setId(0).setName('hero');

var hero2: Hero = new Hero().setId(0).setName('hero');
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12827266/get-and-set-in-typescript

Comment: This might help maybe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12713659/typescript-private-members

Comment: Take note that `hero instanceof Hero === true` while `hero2 instanceof Hero === false` so they are not the same.

Comment: There is no such thing as "class attributes". You probably mean "class properties". There is no such thing as "instanciating" [sic] a property. You probably mean "set". Anyway, if you wanted to know if what you wrote worked, just try it (and you will find that it does).

Answer (score 1):

Java is a statically compiled language. In Java, if you publish a JAR library with a class,

```java
class Foo {
  public int bar;
}
```

And later decide to introduce a logic around that field,

```java
class Foo {
  private int _bar;
  public int getBar() { return _bar - 1; }
  public void setBar(int v) { _bar = v + 1; }
}
```

Any code that uses your JAR file will break and will have to be updated and recompiled. This is why it's a big no-no in Java to expose raw public fields.

TypeScript is a superset of JavaScript which is a dynamic language. All linking is dynamic. You can safely release a library with a class,

```
class Foo {
  bar: number
}
```

If you later release an update,

```
class Foo {
  private _bar: number
  get bar() { return this._bar - 1 }
  set bar(v: number) { this._bar = v + 1 }
}
```

your library users won't notice.

Answer (score 0):

The TypeScript code is converted into plain JavaScript code, so... if you need something before or after set value, how to log, you to implement.

If no needed, getter and setters is overkill.
The instantiate and setters, for me, is the same to Java.

Example:

```
export class Person{
    public name: string;
    public anotherAttribute: string;
    private age: number;
    private _birth: Date;

    public set birth(birt: Date){
       this._birth = birth;
       this.age = calculateAge(birth);
    }
    .......
}


let person: Person = new Person();
person.name = "John";
......
```

Answer (score -1):

> Is there a Java style convention (like this)

You can do that (and in fact I have). People use `getter` / `setter` as well:

```
export class Hero {
   private _id: number;

   set id(id: number) {
      this._id = id;
   }
}
```

However, be careful not to put too much logic in setters: https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/tips/propertySetters.html. I generally prefer explicit function calls.

```
var hero2: Hero = {id : 0, name: "hero"};
```

This is a weakness (or convenience strength) of the *structural* nature of TypeScript's type checking. [More on this](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/why-typescript.html).

Comment: Nobody forbids you from doing that but it's not the convention and it's overdeclarative and can get pretty ugly very quickly

Comment: This approach actually answers the OP's question and is accurate with a reasonable caution, and is referenced in the TypeScript docs https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#accessors

Answer (score -1):

> is there a Java style convention

Well, you can do it if you want, but since they're different languages, you probably should use TypeScript conventions which usually directly access "members" via the `.` notation... That is way more readable to anyone who works with TypeScript... And arguably to Java developers as well :) as much as I love Java I do realise coding conventionally would have me typing two times what is useful.

In fact, it's a common joke among developers that languages such as Java are overdeclarative.

TL;DR no... use myObject.myMember to access members directly.

Answer (score -1):

Is it because of the extra code around setting the individual properties that you want to use the Java style? If so, you can declare the properties in the constructor of the class.

**Hero class**

```
export class Hero {
  constructor(public id?: number, public name?: string) {}
}
```

**Declarations**

```
const hero1 = new Hero(1, 'hero');
const hero2 = new Hero();
```