# Why are private members accessible through the square bracket notation?

Tags: typescript

Consider the following little snippet:

```
class BlueprintNode {
    private metadata: number[] = [];
}

var node = new BlueprintNode();
node["metadata"].push("Access violation, rangers lead the way.");
```

[Demo on TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=class%20BlueprintNode%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20private%20metadata%3A%20number%5B%5D%20%3D%20%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20node%20%3D%20new%20BlueprintNode()%3B%0D%0Anode%5B%22metadata%22%5D.push(%22Access%20violation%2C%20rangers%20lead%20the%20way.%22)%3B%0D%0A)

How come the TypeScript compiler allows access to a private member through the use of the square-bracket notation? It even correctly detects the type of the given property. With the dot notation, it displays a compile error correctly.

Comment: I guess this is because the square-bracket notation works with any Object and TypeScript wants to be as close to JavaScript as possible. I think it doesn't make sense to try to restrict you from using square brackets, even if the compiler is able to checked that `node["metadata"]` is in fact a private property because you can always bypass this check by using variables like `node[propName]`.  
Have a look at this answer btw: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12713869/310726

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When accessing object properties using indexes the compiler will treat the object like this:

```
interface BlueprintNode {
    metadata: number[];
    [key: string]: any;
}
```

If you then do:

```
let node: BlueprintNode;
node["metadata"].push("Access violation, rangers lead the way.");
```

You'll get the same error as with your code.

Answer (score 0):

See [microsoft/TypeScript#19335](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/19335) for a canonical answer to this question. According to [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/19335#issuecomment-338003928):

> The string index notation has been an escape hatch to allow users to get hold of the private members, e.g. to use them in unit tests, etc.. it is a slightly more type safe alternative to `(t as any).x`.
>
> Our experience shows that users do not stumble into this by mistake.

So it's an intentional way to allow access to [`private` class members](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#private).

Answer (score -1):

Why TypeScript allows accessing private method using square brackets:

```
const privateMethodClass: PrivateMethodClass = new PrivateMethodClass();

let result: boolean;

result = privateMethodClass.getFlag();  //result = false

// Accessing private method using square brackets

privateMethodClass&#91; "setFlag" &#93;( true );

result = privateMethodClass.getFlag();  //Result = true

class PrivateMethodClass {

    private flag: boolean = false;

    private setFlag( flag: boolean ): void {
        this.flag = flag;
    }

    public getFlag(): boolean {
        return this.flag;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).