# TypeScript accessbility of class members

Tags: typescript

From https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#1.6

> The 'public' keyword denotes that the constructor parameter is to be retained as a field. Public is the default accessibility for class members, but a programmer can also specify private or protected accessibility for a class member. Accessibility is a design-time construct; it is enforced during static type checking but does not imply any runtime enforcement.

I wonder why it couldn't be enforced during runtime... Or perhaps it's intentionally designed this way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeScript private members](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12713659/typescript-private-members)

Comment: Just like with type-checking, private is only enforced in compilation time but isn't present at runtime. Typescript is a superset of javascript, meaning that it has features that js does not, when compiled into js all of those features are removed to make it compatible.

Comment: I agree.  Thanks for the insight!

Answer (score -1):

> Accessibility is a design-time construct; it is enforced during static type checking but does not imply any runtime enforcement.

This is covered in the FAQ https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#you-should-emit-classes-like-this-so-they-have-real-private-members

Comment: I'm afraid that I don't follow...  Are you saying that it's impossible to implement a truly private member in TypeScript because of its compilation into javascript?  In that case, it's an unfortunate choice rather than being designed on purpose.