# Testing an API call in Angular 2

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, spy

I have the following 2 components and a single service that is shared by both. I need to unit test them but I'm unable to figure out how to test the dependency of the service on the following components.

```
//a.component.ts
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { SharedService } from './shared/shared.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'a',
  providers: [],
  templateUrl: './a.component.html'
})
export class AComponent {
  ax = {};

  constructor(public helperService: SharedService) {
    helperService.getFromAPI().subscribe(data => this.ax = data["people"]);
  }

}



//b.component.ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { SharedService } from './shared/shared.service';
import { Subscription }   from 'rxjs/Subscription';


@Component({
  selector: 'b',
  providers: [],
  templateUrl: './b.component.html'
})

export class BComponent {
  subscription: Subscription;
  x = '';

  constructor(public helperService: SharedService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription = this.helperService.c$.subscribe(
      data => {
        this.x = data;
      });
  }
}
```

This is the service that calls the API. The other function `setC` add the value to the observable upon a button click and this value is to be accessed by the `BComponent`.

```
// shared.service
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class SharedService {

  private c = new Subject<string>();
  c$ = this.c.asObservable();

  constructor(
    private http: Http
  ) { }

  getFromAPI() {
    return this.http.get('url')
      .map((res: Response) => res.json());
  }

  setC(data: string) {
    this.c.next(data);
  }
}
```

How can I test this in Jasmine? So far, my efforts have been futile.

I've tried doing like

```
it('xxx', inject([SharedService], (service: SharedService) => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AComponent);
    const app = fixture.componentInstance;

    spyOn(service, 'c$').and.callThrough;

    service.setC('Random Name');
    expect(service.c$).toHaveBeenCalled();

  }));
```

This fails the test with `Expected spy c$ to have been called.`.

Comment: The [tag:angularjs] tag is for angular 1.x only, for Angular 2+ use tag: [tag:angular]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're spying on an `Observable` it seems but what's called when you call `setC` is the `next` function of your Subject. So you probably want to spy on that instead.

Something like `spyOn(service.c, 'next').and.callThrough()` should do the trick.

Hope it helps.

---

Update: If you want explicitely to test the functionality of your `Observable` then i would just subscribe to it, call `setC` and test the response, something like this:

```
service.$c.subscribe((data) => {
    expect(data).toBe('foobar');
});
service.setC('foobar');
```

---

To answer your question in the comment: Since your `c` is private you can spy on it like this: `spyOn(service['c'], 'next').and.callThrough()`.
It could be that your ide will nag about spying on private methods, in this case you can add the `any` type like this: `spyOn<any>(...)`

Comment: But `c` is `private`. How can I spy on that?

Comment: @SadarAli It doesn't answer your question per se but [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12713659/typescript-private-members) might be helpful

Comment: @lexith This trick works if I remove `c` as private. How should I proceed if I want to mock the `getFromAPI` call (with some json) using a similar kind of spy?

Comment: Do you mean how you would test `getFromApi`? Yes use a spy on the `get` method of `http` like `spyOn<any>(service['http'], 'get');` Within your component you probably would want to test the response though, which is another question (then you would have to mock http using `MockBackend`)