# Accessing 'this' from catch clause after firing a promise

Tags: angular

Using the `this` keyword from within a `catch` clause after firing a promise  reports "this" as being `undefined`.
 What i want to do is simple, i have a `Router` object injected in the constructor of a service, from a method i fire an http request via a client, in case the response `!=2*` then i want to redirect the user.
For some reason,  the current object (the service), seems gone, it looks like the `catch` is executed in another thread that is totally unaware of the service:
The constructor:

```
constructor(private router: Router) { }

public sendRequestOrRedirect(){
var url = environment.url
var json = //someJSON here
return this.httpClient.patch(url,json).toPromise().then(res=>{
  return res;
}).catch(err => this.handleErrorResponse(err));
```

}

```
private handleErrorResponse (error: Response | any) {
      if(error.status == 401){
        this.router.navigate['/getout'];
        return Promise.reject(error.status);
      }
   }
  }
```

So the result of `this.router`will eventually throw an error saying that `this` is actually undefined.
Any suggestion about how i could solve this and more importantly, why it happens?

Answer (score 2):

It is all happening because when you do

```
.catch(this.handleErrorResponse);
```

Here `this` has limitations to its scope. It is currently a scope of `catch` function.

What you need is a [`lexical scoping`](https://toddmotto.com/es6-arrow-functions-syntaxes-and-lexical-scoping/#functionality-lexical-scoping-this)

> The ES6 arrow function syntax uses “lexical scoping” to figure out
>   what the value of “this” should be. Lexical scoping is fancy way of
>   saying it uses “this” from the surrounding code… the code that
>   contains the code in question.

So when we do

```
.catch(err => this.handleErrorResponse(err)); //here this points to its module's scope
```

Comment: thank you but did not help, i still get: TypeError: Cannot read property 'router' of undefined

Comment: @JBoy, is `handleErrorResponse` is a closure function ? as I can see it is a private closure function of `sendRequestOrRedirect`. Is this you did intentionally?

Comment: yes, i did this intentionally, i have edited the code as suggested to apply lexical scoping, i was not aware of this, i usually develop in Java which does not have this feature. The problem persists, the function is declared private because this class is the only place where the function should be invoked from.

Comment: @JBoy, Now when you edited your question , this now separates private function as to be another function of the class. Are you sure this is not a closure function ? Tell me if its confusing. with the closure I meant a function into function

Comment: i was not aware there is a difference between a closure function and a private class-scope function, i created it as separate function because i did not want to create too much spaghetti code in the same place.

Comment: @JBoy, Can you make that function public and see if you get `this` ? However, I don't think this should be a problem though
see - https://stackoverflow.com/a/38390379/1982631

Comment: it still does not work when you invoke it as an external function, regardless of its scope, it does work when its an enclosed function `.catch((err) => {
      if(err.status == 401){
        console.log("Got a 401")
      }
    });`

Answer (score 0):

Try using this syntax :

```
.catch(err => this.handleErrorResponse(err));
```

Comment: thank you but did not help, i still get: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'router' of undefined`

Comment: Your answer is the exact same as mine or @Manoj. I'm guessing you resolved your scoping issue by editing your code, that's all.

Comment: no, the function is now defined within the `catch` clause, while before it was a class-member method. thx

Comment: According to your issue, it wasn't a class member ... But great if you resolved it.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it with an inner function:

```
constructor(private router: Router) { }

    public sendRequestOrRedirect(){
    var url = environment.url
    var json = //someJSON here
    return this.httpClient.patch(url,json).toPromise().then(res=>{
      return res;
    }).catch((err) => {
          if(err.status == 401){
            console.log("Got a 401")
            this.router.navigate(['/getout'])
          }
        });
    }
```