# Lack of access to class properties

Tags: typescript, class, oop, properties, access-modifiers

I have a stopwatch method that has several properties, I want no one to be able to access them from outside the class, I made them private, but it is still possible to access them and their value can be changed.
what do I do?

```
class StopWatch {
    private duration: number = 0;
    private status: string = 'stopped';
    private currentTime: number = 0;
    start () {
        if (this.status == 'started') {
            throw new Error("already started!");
        }
        this.currentTime = Date.now();
        this.status = "started";
    }
    stop() {
        if (this.status == "stopped") {
            throw new Error("already stopped!");
        }
        this.duration = Date.now() - this.currentTime + this.duration;
        this.status = "stopped";
        console.log((this.duration / 1000).toFixed(1));
    }
    reset() {
        if (this.status == 'started') {
            this.stop();
        }
        this.duration = 0;
    }
}
const obj = new StopWatch();
```

Comment: Please visit the below thread on how to make a truly private member inside the class which cannot be accessible as a member of the  class

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12713659/why-can-i-access-typescript-private-members-when-i-shouldnt-be-able-to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by Hrusikesh in the question comments, TypeScript [visibility modifiers](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#member-visibility) are enforced only at compile time. At runtime, your class members are always accessible like any JavaScript object properties:

> Like other aspects of TypeScript’s type system, `private` and `protected` are only enforced during type checking.

But there are now JavaScript class [private features](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_class_fields): just prefix the member name with a hash (`#`), and it will be truly "private", i.e. not accessible from outside the class, even after compilation, since it is enforced by JavaScript:

```
class StopWatch2 {
    #duration: number = 0;

    method() {
        console.log("method", this.#duration);
    }
}

const obj2 = new StopWatch2();
obj2.method();
// [LOG]: "method",  0 

console.log("obj2", obj2.#duration); // Error: Property '#duration' is not accessible outside class 'StopWatch2' because it has a private identifier.
// Does not even run!
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)