# Why does array.map convert class instance to object?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an array called `Users[]` which holds class instances of `User`. I create this array by mapping over query results like so:

```js
function GetUserByUserData(data : UserData[] | ReadonlyArray<UserData>) : User[]
{
    return data.map((userData) => {
        return new User(userData);
    });
}
```

*Note: `UserData` is an object of type `{id: number; [key: string]: any;}`*.
Then, I use a method to create rows based on some class properties like so:

```js
//User class
export default class User
{
    private _data: UserData;
    get data()
    {
        return this._data;
    }
}
```

```js
let rows = Users.map((user) => makeRowFromUser(user));

function makeRowFromUser(user: User)
{
    console.log(user); //logs {_data}
    console.log(user.data); //undefined
    console.log(user._data); //logs data normally
}
```

I realize since `_data` is private I shouldn't be able to access it using `user._data`.

Why does this happen? Does `array.map` destructure the `Users[]` array? Does the `user` argument get destructured before being passed to the function? And since this is unintended behavior on my part, is there a way to prevent this from happening so I can pass the `User` class instance as a class instance?

---

#### Edit

My actual code does the following:

1. An API call is made to fetch users.
2. Query a database for user information which it gets as `unknwon[]` and converts to `UserData[]`

```js
function ConvertUknownResultToUserData(raw : unknown[]) : ReadonlyArray<UserData>
{
    return raw.map<UserData>((e : any) : UserData => ({
        id: e.user_id,
        name_first: e.name_first,
        name_last: e.name_last,
        //...
    }));
}
```

3. It creates a `User[]` using the `UserData[]`, using the `GetUserByUserData` method.

```js
function GetUserByUserData(data : UserData[] | ReadonlyArray<UserData>) : User[]
{
    return data.map((userData) => {
        return new User(userData);
    });
}
```

4. The promise is resolved and table rows are made like so:

```js
//inside a Svelte component...
await window.api.GetUsers().
    then((value) => {
        return value.map((user) => makeRowFromUser(user));
    });
```

5. Table rows are displayed...

The problem appears to happen at the 4th step, after the API promise is resolved which returns `User[]`.

Comment: It's not `map`, it's `Users` which is not an array of `User` instances. Please show us how you are creating the array.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12713659/why-can-i-access-typescript-private-members-when-i-shouldnt-be-able-to

Comment: @Bergi I updated my question, and I believe you might have struck the nail on the head with this one but I'm still unsure. I hope this helps.

Comment: I don't see that `makeRowFromUser` returns anything

Comment: @Anatoly I believe that is irrelevant to the question as the problem happens before I have the chance to process anything. I simply cannot call `User.data` but I can call `User._data`.

Comment: what if you try `console.log(user.data());`?

Comment: @IłyaBursov This logs `data` normally! I don't understand why though. Do you know why this happens?

Comment: do you know difference between properties and methods? there is no `data` property, there is `data()` method

Comment: @IłyaBursov that's a getter, it shouldn't require being explicitly called, and I [cannot reproduce this with the OPs code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAE2AMwIYFcA28DGnUDOBcAqgcFAFADelc9cYUAlgG6ozBwD6CHqALjgA7dAFsARhQDcdBgHNg8PjFQAKAJRz6tBnrhQl6KMLgwAFswIA6Xv1l6AvpW1wcEYQRhR0OGNDhNOF19egsrWxVUOABeOAAmBwZnZ0p3T3h0cihYkWAAd1JszVl0gghMYGtMCHk1LIprKI1Sj3LK6tr67Mj+FrS2iqqauoaoJv5NFqA) everything works for me as intended.

Comment: It's not your problem here (I don't think) Lae but you should really use the K&R style of braces instead of the Allman style for JS because of [ASI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846283/what-are-the-rules-for-javascripts-automatic-semicolon-insertion-asi). My best guess as to your *actual* problem is that `Users` is of type `any[]` instead of `User[]` but as Bergi said we'd need to see how that's defined.

Comment: I will update my answer to include a more detailed description of the problem. Thanks for the pointer @JaredSmith, I will try to remember that in the future!

Comment: I believe you have a typo. `new User(UserData)` should be `new User(userData)`.

Comment: Where are you calling `GetUserByUserData`? It seems it is happening on the server, where the db query and `ConvertUknownResultToUserData` are executed, but then the response is serialised to JSON and parsed to a plain object on the client side. You'll need to call `GetUserByUserData` after the API returns `UserData`.

Comment: @Bergi You are right. That fixed the issue. If you post this as answer, I will accept it.